# How to create a "Spool" service for a class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, critical-section, spool

I am looking into a C# programming fairly scrub to the language. I would like to think I have a good understanding of object oriented programming in general, and what running multiple threads means, at a high level, but actual implementation I am as said scrub.

What I am looking to do is to create a tool that will have many threads running and interacting with each other independent, each will serve their own task and may call others.

My strategy to ensure communication (without losing anything with multiple updates occurring same time from different threads) is on each class to create a spool like task that can be called external, and add tasks to a given thread, or spool service for these. I am not sure if I should place this on the class or external and have the class itself call the spool for new tasks and keeping track of the spool. Here I am in particular considering how to signal the class if an empty spool gets a task (listener approach, so tasks can subscribe to pools if they want to be awoken if new stuff arrive), or make a "check every X seconds if out of tasks and next task is not scheduled" approach

What would a good strategy be to create this, should I create this in the actual class, or external? What are the critical regions in the implementation, as the "busy wait check" allows it to only be on adding new jobs, and removing jobs on the actual spool, while the signaling will require both adding/removing jobs, but also the goto sleep on signaling to be critical, and that suddenly add a high requirement for the spool of what to do if the critical region has entered, as this could result in blocks, causing other blocks, and possible unforeseen deadlocks.

Comment: wow I think this is a very open-ended question. There is a lot written about this kind of system (mostly called Agents) - just search for Agent-Based systems.

Comment: Yeah dropped straight into the deep end, trying to not sink. Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it. What I am aiming for is a "pattern" that can help me out with a good approach for this. Figuring out the actual implementation once I find the right pattern is gonna be half the fun.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand all of your question, but the [active object design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object) might be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use such a model often, on various systems.  I define a class for the agents, say 'AgentClass' and one for the requests, say 'RequestClass'.  The agent has two abstract methods, 'submit(RequestClass *message)' and 'signal()'. Typically, a thread in the agent constructs a producer-consumer queue and waits on it for RequestClass instances, the submit() method queueing the passed RequestClass instances to the queue.  The RequestClass usually contains a 'command' enumeration that tells the agent what needs doing, together with all data required to perform the request and the 'sender' agent instance.  When an agent gets a request, it switches on the enumeration to call the correct function to do the request.  The agent acts only on the data in the RequestClass - results, error messages etc. are placed in data members of the RequestClass. When the agent has performed the request, (or failed and generated error data), it can either submit() the request back to the sender, (ie. the request has been performed asynchronously), or call the senders signal() function, whch signals an event upon which the sender was waiting, (ie. the request was performed synchronously).

I usually construct a fixed number of RequestClass instances at startup and store them in a global 'pool' P-C queue.  Any agent/thread/whatever than needs to send a request can dequeue a RequestClass instance, fill in data, submit() it to the agent and then wait asynchronously or synchronously for the request to be performed.  When done with, the RequestClass is returned to the pool.  I do this to avoid continual malloc/free/new/dispose, ease debugging, (I dump the pool level to a status bar using a timer, so I always notice if a request leaks or gets double-freed), and to eliminate the need for explicit thread termination on app close, (if multiple threads are only ever reading/writing to data areas that outlive the application forms etc, the app will close easily and the OS can deal with all the threads - there are hundreds of posts about 'cleanly shutting down threads upon app close' - I never bother!).

Such message-passing designs are quite resistant to deadlocks since the only locks, (if any), are in the P-C queues, though you can certainly achieve it if you try hard enough:)

Is this the sort of system that you seem to need , or have I got it wrong?

Rgds,
Martin